# Facebook login Oauth issue: “URL Blocked"

Tags: wordpress, facebook, authentication, oauth

My website is: `https://www.countrygag.com`

The link into my Facebook Login button is: `https://www.countrygag.com/wp-login.php?action=wordpress_social_authenticate&mode=login&provider=Facebook&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.countrygag.com%2F`

The key and secret key is correct on my website. I have added all possible variations on the Valid Oauth URL but still no success. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
The link is probably incorrect, but how can I find the correct link? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the right link on the Wordpress plugin instrucitons. Thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

You can use this as a plugin or can paste the entire code in functions.php

```html
<?php
require_once("inc/facebookoauth.php");
class Facebook_Login_Widget extends WP_Widget 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct("facebook_login_widget", "Facebook Login", array("description" => __("Display a Facebook Login Button")));
    }
        
    public function form( $instance ) 
    {
        // Check values
        if($instance) 
        {
            $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
            $app_key = $instance['app_key'];
            $app_secret = $instance['app_secret'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            $title = '';
            $app_key = '';
            $app_secret = '';
        }
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title', 'facebook_login_widget'); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('app_key'); ?>"><?php _e('App ID:', 'facebook_login_widget'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('app_key'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('app_key'); ?>" value="<?php echo $app_key; ?>" />
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('app_secret'); ?>"><?php _e('App Secret:', 'facebook_login_widget'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('app_secret'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('app_secret'); ?>" value="<?php echo $app_secret; ?>" />
        </p>
        
        <?php
    }
        
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) 
    {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['app_key'] = strip_tags($new_instance['app_key']);
        $instance['app_secret'] = strip_tags($new_instance['app_secret']);
        
        update_option("facebook_app_id", $new_instance['app_key']);
        update_option("facebook_app_secret", $new_instance['app_secret']);
        
        return $instance;
    }
        
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) 
    {
        extract($args);
        
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        echo $before_widget;
        
        if($title) 
        {
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title ;
        }
        
        if(is_user_logged_in()) 
        {
            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Logout"><input type="button" value="Logout" /></a>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=facebook_oauth_redirect'; ?>"><input type="button" value="Login Using Facebook" /></a>
            <?php
        }
        
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}
register_widget("Facebook_Login_Widget");
```